# Sql Agent Cannot Find the File Specified

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server

I have a SQL 2008 Agent job with a single `Operating system (CmdExec)` step:

```
C:\Scripts\Script.cmd
```

`Script.cmd` runs a [CS-Script](http://csscript.net/index.html).

If I run `C:\Scripts\Script.cmd`, everything appears fine - I get my expected logging output and `echo %ERRORLEVEL%` shows 0 afterwards.

When I run it through SqlAgent, though - I get my expected logging output and then

```
The system cannot find the file specified.  
Process Exit Code 1.  
The step failed.
```

The logging output is complete and correct, so it *does* run the batch file and the EXE that the batch file calls. The last thing the CS-Script does is:

```
Console.WriteLine("Exiting at 2009-09-22 16:10:32 with Status {0}", exitCode);
return (int)exitCode;
```

which is logged in the output, and in entirety.

What file can't it find?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clearing CS-Script's cache did the trick. Procmon didn't really help, but did show hits to the user's cache folder in `C:\Users\sql-agent-svc\AppData\Local\Temp\CSSCRIPT\Cache` which prompted me to try clearing it.

Since it's a per-user cache, running CS-Script as an admin manually used a different cache which didn't have the issue.

As I understand it, the cache is only to avoid recompilation of an unchanged script - so it really shouldn't cause any issues. But, deleting it and letting CS-Script recreate it seems to have worked.